# filename globbing

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards

I would like to know why these 2 filenames globbing expression

```
[bru][abru]* and [br]*
```

will return me a filename call

```
brutus
```

but will not return me this filename

```
abruti
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `abruti` dose not start with `b`,`r`, or `u`.

For example `[br]*` means starting with `b` or `r`, then anything. `abruti` has a `br` but not in the correct place. A pattern that could be used to match both is `*br*`.

Glob is like regex, but different. In glob * is any amount of any character, like .* in regex). `?` is any character, like `.?` in regex.

Comment: [br]* means starting with b or r ? i though it mean contain b or r. Thanks for info

Comment: Oh I suddenly get what you were thinking. Were you thinking that a glob is a regex? (they are similar, but different. In glob `*` is any amount of any character, like `.*` in regex).

Comment: yep i was confuse between glob and regex. Now i understand thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With examples:

```
find . -name "[bru]*"
boo
roo
uoo
find . -name "[bru][abc]*"
baoo
bboo
bcoo
rboo
ucoo
...
```